# Transit visa for Hong Kong, as a Pakistani National

Tags: visas, transit, hong-kong, pakistani-citizens

I am travelling from Bejing to Karachi, transiting through Hong Kong, flying on Cathay Pacific Airways. I am a Pakistani National holding a Chinese visa. I have gap between the flights about 3 hours mean I will stay Hong Kong airport for 3 hours. Do I need any kind of transit visa? And if yes then how I need to apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a Pakistani national, unfortunately, [you need a valid Visa](http://www.immd.gov.hk/en/services/hk-visas/visit-transit/visit-visa-entry-permit.html#notes) for Hong Kong even if you are only transiting and never leave the airside in Hong Kong airport.

You will most likely get one however since it says [on this page](http://www.immd.gov.hk/en/services/hk-visas/immigration-entry-guideline.html#visit_transit) that:

> An application for an entry visa/permit to enter Hong Kong for a visit (leisure, social or business) or transit may be favourably considered if [...] the application is for a transit visa/permit, he/she holds an onward ticket to the place of his/her destination unless the destination is the Mainland of China or the Macao SAR.

Transit visa are [84 HKD](http://www.immd.gov.hk/en/services/hk-visas/fee-table.html).

Comment: @HaLaBi and wrong, too! :) fixed it now

Comment: That sucks... Agent didnt tell me and I realized it after buying ticket.. refunding it charged me 1300 yuan :-(